# Trouble Accessing Node.js and Express Server from Static IP Address

Tags: node.js, express, webserver

So I'm basically moving over a node.js and express server from LocalHost to a static IP address instead (so I'm able to access it remotely without my local computer).

I feel pretty certain on the code I have written which is fairly simple my node.js standards. The goal is to serve static files, include API routes, and then start the express server though my Static IP. This has all worked perfect on LocalHost previously. Here's what I have so far.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

// Serve static files from the dist folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));

// Include your API routes
app.use("/api", require("./functions/api"));

// Start the Express server with Static IP Address
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, "my static IP", () => {
  console.log("Server is running at http://mystaticIP:8080" + "\nPort Number: " + port);
});
```

Whenever I type in the static IP url through another computer I get a timed out error. My assumption is that the firewall could be the problem.

[web error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NORGY.png)

Comment: Is your static ip publicly accessible? You wouldn't normally serve http requests over port `8080` on a publicly facing ip address, that's usually done behind a proxy that takes http request on the normal port `80` and then route them to your server on `8080`. Is your server on a cloud platform AWS/Azure etc?

Comment: the 8080 port is not publicaly accessible but should be through intranet instead. I also know it is a server on a virtual machine but unsure of which one (this project is through school, so I'm not fully aware of the permissions and accesses to the server). Alternatively, I could switch to port 80 instead.